# how to get rid of discoloration?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I made this using more then one object, then joined them together. used some fill faces as well. [image]Then when I put the subdivision mod on it I get this three color pattern on the now Whole oject. Is that normal? I think not. so if I am right how to I get it to show all of it in the same color?

Comment: what is the heading ?? Having taking the time out of your life to add this notice you could at least diriect me to that. Instead of change it ...